# react navigation modal swipe

Tags: ios, react-native, modal-dialog, react-navigation

I am currently using react-navigation in a project and running into a view issues.
I have two main screens, `Login` and `Main`. After logging in a user is taken to the `Main` screen. The main screen has a camera button which opens a Camera component in a modal view.

**Issue**
Swiping from left to right on the camera modal goes back to the `Login` screen. I need it to go back to the Main screen.

Here's how I have it setup:

```
export const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
})

export const MainStack = StackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: Blurts,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      headerLeft: null,
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
  },

  Camera: {
    screen: CameraView,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      headerLeft: null,
    }
  }
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none'
})

const Root = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginStack
  },
  Main: {
    screen: MainStack
  }
})


export default Root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest setting `gesturesEnabled: false` for the Main screen on the Root navigator

```
const Root = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginStack
  },
  Main: {
    screen: MainStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
  }
})
```

That way the `MainStack` should pick up the gesture r